# ACL9 and Rails 2.3.8 - NameError: uninitialized constant User::Role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acl9

I am running RVM (Ruby 1.8.7-head, Rails 2.3.8) and have the BASICS of a new app running. I have Authlogic working, with the minimal code to make that work. I am attempting to use ACL9 (which I have working on a different project, same RVM gemset)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # authentication
  acts_as_authentic
  
  # authorization
  acts_as_authorization_subject
  
  def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
end
```

When I attempt to just run a simple check to make sure ACL9 is working properly...

> script/console
>
> u = User.first
>
> u.has_role?(:anyrole)

I get this error...

```
ruby-1.8.7-head > u.has_role?(:anyrole)
NameError: uninitialized constant User::Role
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2230:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:156:in `send'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:156:in `klass'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:187:in `quoted_table_name'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association.rb:102:in `construct_sql'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:21:in `initialize'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association.rb:5:in `initialize'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1306:in `new'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1306:in `role_objects'
    from /Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails238/gems/acl9-0.12.0/lib/acl9/model_extensions/for_subject.rb:39:in `has_role?'
    from (irb):2
```

I'm not sure why this works with every other app I have, but not this one - and I'm not sure what the error message is saying.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_authorization_role
  end
```